# Shared Spreadsheet with two instances of onEdit, deleting wrong row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a lead management format using Google Sheets & Apps Script.

The apps script is checking whether the value in column **M** of sheet **Propsect** or **Interested** has changed and depending on the value, moving the row to the respective sheet (**Interested**, **Postponed**, **Lost**, or **Booked**)

The spreadsheet is shared with my team who'll make changes and with multiple users editing at a time.

Now, the problem is that, as soon as two `onEdit`s are triggered, and if both require rows to be moved, the first instance runs properly but the second one removes the wrong row.

Eg: In sheet **Prospect**, Row 2 & Row 3 have status changed to `Lost` & `Postponed` at the same time. Now, `Lost` gets triggered properly, however, the `Postponed` instance deletes the 4th row (now the 3rd row, as row 2 was removed before).

I have tried to add in `lockservice` to the code so that only one instance is running but that doesn't seem to solve the problem as the event object is still considering the un-updated row number.
Even tried adding `flush()` at the start & end of the code but didn't work either.

You can access the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LAJgGkTW68y3e-syrHaNjZ0_wED0zKQmZ5G3-DQKEjc/edit#gid=0).

My code is as follows:

```
function Master(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  var SS = e.source;
  var Sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var Range = e.range;
  if(Sheet.getName() == "Prospect" && Range.getColumn() == "13" || Sheet.getName() == "Interested" && Range.getColumn() == "13"){
    moveRows(SS,Sheet,Range);
  } 
lock.releaseLock();
}

function moveRows(SS,Sheet,Range) {
  var val1 = Sheet.getRange(Range.getRow(),1,1,10).getDisplayValues();
  val1 = String(val1).split(",");
  var tar_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Range.getValue());
  var row = tar_sheet.getRange(tar_sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,val1.length).setValues([val1]);
  Sheet.deleteRow(Range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Is there any way for the second `onEdit` to run only after the first has completed execution? I guess, if that could happen, the problem would be solved?
I Hope I have been able to convey my question properly.

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

Event object `e` passed to a `onEdit(e)` is not altered, when two or more edits are done at the same time and the first edit alters the next edit's row number- making `e.range.rowStart` of the second+ edit unreliable at the time of it's execution.

#### Possible Solutions:

- Do not delete the rows immediately. Mark them for deletion(save the range string in properties service) and delete them later(time trigger), when document is not in use.
- Alternatively, Add code guards: Check `range.getValue()===e.value`. If they're equal, continue to `moveRows` else keep `offset`ing the range by -1 row until they're both equal.

#### References:

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- [Range#offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))

Comment: How is the first part of the code working properly though?
`var val1 = Sheet.getRange(Range.getRow(),1,1,10).getDisplayValues();` is copying data from the actual row and not the row beneath it.
Shouldn't this have copied the data from the wrong row aswell?

Comment: @Anuj Try adding a flush() after setValues()

Comment: Trying the 2nd method you've suggested - It's still not working, sometimes it deletes the right row, sometimes it's deleting the row underneath.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should trigger only one function based on user interaction and then inside that perform conditional operations.

Something like this:

```
function onEdit(event_object) {
    var sheet = event_object.range.getSheet();
    var row = event_object.range.getRow();
    var column = event_object.range.getColumn();

    if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
        // perform operations when Sheet1 is edited
    } else if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet2") {
        // perform operations when Sheet2 is edited
    }
}
```

Reference :

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit

Comment: It's not making a difference, the 4th row still gets deleted.
The problem is that, when the second `onEdit` is running, the 4th row is becoming the 3rd row which is causing the wrong row to get deleted.

Comment: Before deleting row check the condition, don't delete for 2nd time.